# PostgreSQL-Error in 'yyyy;-Value should be integer

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, postgresql-9.3

I wrote the following commands on PostgreSQL:

```
create table Daily_Winners as (
    select d.* from 
    (
        select row_number() over(partition by "request_date",
                                              "revised_circle" 
                                 order by "earned_score" desc,
                                          "count_of_attempts" asc) rn,
                * 
        from 
        (
            select a.*,b.count_of_attempts, last_que_attempt 
            from
            (
                select msisdn, revised_circle, 
                       to_date(left(a.request_date,10),'yyyy-mm-dd')request_date,
                       sum(cast(score as numeric(10,0))) Earned_Score 
                from Airtel_season13_circles_final a  
                where upper(a.ans_type)='CA' 
                group by Revised_Circle, 
                         to_date(left(a.request_date,10),'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                         msisdn
            )a 
            join 
            (
                select distinct revised_circle, 
                       to_date(left(a.request_date,10),'yyyy-mm-dd')request_date,
                       msisdn,
                       count(distinct transaction_id) count_of_attempts, 
                       max(to_timestamp(request_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone)last_que_attempt 
                from Airtel_season13_circles_final a 
                group by revised_circle, 
                         to_date(left(a.request_date,10),'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                         msisdn
            )b 
            on a.msisdn=b.msisdn and a.revised_circle=b.revised_circle
            and a.request_date=b.request_date
        )c
    )d 
     where d.rn<=20)
```

The execution of this gave me the following error:

> ERROR:  invalid value "requ" for "yyyy"
>   DETAIL:  Value must be an
>   integer.

Can anyone please help with this? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your field `request_date` is a text, and for at least one row the 4 four left most characters are not 4 digits but the string REQU.

When you try to convert the string to a date, you specify the format, and there is no value compatible with the format your specify

--> you must either filter your bad data, or fix your string exactraction, or even better, save the date in a `date` field.